# react-i18next issue translating json values from translation file

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I'm developing a multilanguage site and in several sections I use a hardcoded json to store some clients details (name, logo, project description and website) and then I map the json file and print the details using a component nothing fancy.

The problem is that I'm trying to set multilanguage and I don't know why when I try to set translated values to the json is not working. This is how I'm trying it now:

This is my react component:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { t } = useTranslation();
const companyADescription = t("projects.companyA.name");




    {
          name: "Company A",
          url: "company.com",
          image: "/assets/projects/a.png",
          technologies: [
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/react.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/firebase.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
          ],
          description: t("project.companyA.name"),
        },
{
          name: "Company B",
          url: "company.com",
          image: "/assets/projects/b.png",
          technologies: [
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/react.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/firebase.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
          ],
          description: t("projects.companyB.name"),
        },
```

And this is my json file with the translation:

```
"projects": {
    "companyA": {
      "name": "Company A Project",
      "description": "This is the company project description A"
    }
  }
```

On other sections I use the `t` function from the `useTranslation` hook and works well I already spent a lot of time on this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
description: t("project.companyA.name")
```

The function isnt being called

You can try this above declaration of JSON

```
const descriptionA = t("project.companyA.name")
const descriptionB = t("projects.companyB.name")
```

And then assign the values in JSON as

```
    {
          name: "Company A",
          url: "company.com",
          image: "/assets/projects/a.png",
          technologies: [
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/react.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/firebase.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
          ],
          description: descriptionA ,
        },
{
          name: "Company B",
          url: "company.com",
          image: "/assets/projects/b.png",
          technologies: [
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/react.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
            {
              icon: "/assets/tech/firebase.png",
              link: "#",
              alt: "",
            },
          ],
          description: descriptionB ,
        },
```

Comment: I tryed but still doesn't work. I updated the question with more code.

Comment: It seems like I solve it, after declaring the JSON I store it on the component state and I do the map over the state. I just removed the state and did the maping directly over the json and now works